# Checking apachectl configtest from within php

Tags: php, apache

I want to check the content of apachectl configtest from within PHP, but the below code returns an error, yet running it via command line says it is OK.

This code:

```
$output = shell_exec('/usr/sbin/apachectl configtest');
echo $output;
```

Give this:

```
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

But running it directly like this:

```
user@server:~# /usr/sbin/apachectl configtest
```

Give this:

```
Syntax OK
```

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Update : I checked the error and it says this:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 17 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/letsencrypt/live/server/fullchain.pem' does not exist or is empty
```

But that file does exist (well, it's a symlink) and the command works via command line.

Comment: Does the apache logs give you any more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh, my bad, I was trying to access it externally and it didn't work, but when I ran it as a php via command line script it did, so it didn't really matter anyway. Leaving here as it may help somewone.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the user executing PHP doesn't have permissions to access the certificate file but the user in the command line does. In a similar setup, I've run into an error when running `[apache] configtest` but not with `sudo [apache] configtest` (running the same command as a superuser), since the superuser can see the certificate.